m=credential_button_library:66 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID
I am trying to intergrate Signin with google and It is so unfortunate that even the previous answers did not help me at all. The Refferer-policy is done. My origin is 127.0.0.1:8000 but i keep getting an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
m=credential_button_library:66 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID." 


function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    // Handle the credential response (e.g., verify ID token)
    console.log("ID Token: " + response.credential);
}

 window.onload = function() {
  // Initialize Google Sign-In
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    callback: handleCredentialResponse
  });

  // Render the Google Sign-In button
  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById("g_id_signin"),
    { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
  );
};
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade" />
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>



<div id="g_id_signin"></div>




Everything was good the issue was the SSL. I did not find anywhere google mentioning that this wont work for http. When i installed SSL on my localhost (am using xampp) and created a virtual host (mysite.com), i then added mysite.com on Authorized javascript origin and everything worked.
